# gsutil doesn't run in the mounted drive directory

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gsutil, fileshare

I'm trying to run gsutil in the shared environment and I see a really weird behaviour.
When I run it being in the root of the filesystem, as well as anywhere else - everything is fine, but when I open the shared drive mounted directory it fails with this:

`$: gsutil
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied`

The shared drive folder itself is the Google Fileshare NFS with drwxrwxr-x, and the user is in the group that can do rwx.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

---

update: The issue was in the snap way of the installation of the gcloud-sdk, I'm not sure the exact nature of the problem, but reinstalling it following the google-sdk istallation manual with apt-get solved the issue.

Comment: gsutil stores information in subdirectories in the user's home directory. When you reference gsutil from a mounted directory the paths and user home directory are different. gsutil should be installed per user and not via a shared folder mechanism. The exception is if the shared folder is a subdirectory to the user's home directory and gsutil is installed after this drive mapping is complete.

Comment: hm, I don't think that this is my case. GSutil was installed with snap package manager which somehow was wrong, I reinstalled it with apt-get and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: My comments are correct for how gsutil works. You should have edited your question with your findings as a broken installation is a different matter.

Comment: @JohnHanley sure, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue. The snap install does not work on my NFS /home/ mounts.

uninstall the snap:

```
sudo snap remove google-cloud-sdk
```

Follow the [gsutil install instructions provided by google](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#deb).

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli
```

You may need to log out an log back in to refresh the shell environment.
Any previous setup from `gcloud init` should still work.